# Auto click button on page load is not working

Tags: javascript, html, button

I'm completely newbie to code, and I'm making a website on Webflow and trying to adapt some functions with custom code. I read a bunch of topics here that mentions the possibility of auto clicks a button on load of the page. So I tried adding the snippet to the body of the page and publishing the website to check if it would work, but the auto click didn't happen. The page is only a button with an auto click. Could someone help me to understand why it's not working? Thanks in advance.

```
<body>
  <div><a id="redirect" ms-member-page="default" href="#" class="w-button">Button Text</a></div>
  <script src="https://d3e54v103j8qbb.cloudfront.net/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.220afd743d.js?site=5e79526aa1d3ba459f1ebac2" type="text/javascript" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="js/webflow.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- [if lte IE 9]><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/placeholders/3.0.2/placeholders.min.js"></script><![endif] -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("redirect").click();
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The autoclick is working, but it's just the fact that your anchor tag (`a`) is not leading the user anywhere. You probably were trying to do something like this:

```
<body>
  <div><a id="redirect" ms-member-page="default" href="/mypage.html" class="w-button">Button Text</a></div>
  <script src="https://d3e54v103j8qbb.cloudfront.net/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.220afd743d.js?site=5e79526aa1d3ba459f1ebac2" type="text/javascript" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="js/webflow.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- [if lte IE 9]><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/placeholders/3.0.2/placeholders.min.js"></script><![endif] -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("redirect").click();
</script>
</body>
```

Read more about anchor tags [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp).

`a` tags are for links, to send your user to a page. Buttons are made with the `<button>` tag.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense @sportzpikachu, and I think I know how to solve my problem. Thanks!